# How to get the property of an object without using the index

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

So I have this object **(stdClass)** that has a dynamic key.

My problem is since my **key is dynamic (e.g Date, time, id).**

How will I get the value of that dynamic key. without looping it (for the sake of neatness of the code)

**Example :**  `stdClass { [*dynamic key (e.g Date, Time. ID)*] : value }`

**P.S** I'm just looking for an alternative way to get the value, I'm thinking of something like this `$stdClass->{dynamic_key}`

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: PS: Classes dont have keys! Dynamic or otherwise!! Do you mean a database table which you have read into an object???